# JavaScript AddEventListener not working for all containers

Tags: javascript

I have a search bar that is pulling this information from an API and showing the information in a container. When I press the button I want to save the food ID right now I'm just printing it to the console. The code only prints the first button none of the other buttons work.

```
    function test(foodId){
  console.log(foodId);
}

 function generateHTML(results){
   console.log(results);
  container.classList.remove('initial');
  let generatedHTML= '';
  results.map(result => {
    generatedHTML += `
      <div class="item">
        <div class="flex-container">
          <h1 class="title">${result.food.label}</h1>
          <button id="button"  value="${result.food.foodId}" class="btn btn-primary">View</button>
        </div>
        <p  id="Food" value="${result.food.foodId}" class="item-data" >${result.food.foodId}</p>
        <p class="item-data">Brand: ${result.food.brand}</p>
        <p class="item-data">Calories: ${result.food.nutrients.ENERC_KCAL.toFixed(2)}</p>
        <p class="item-data">Fat: ${result.food.nutrients.FAT.toFixed(2)}</p>
        <p class="item-data">Protein: ${result.food.nutrients.PROCNT.toFixed(2)}</p>
      </div>
    `
  })
  
  searchResultDiv.innerHTML = generatedHTML;
    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click",function(){
    test(document.getElementById("Food").innerText);
     
  });  
}
```

What I get now
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOzMB.png)

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you should read about event delegation?

```js
function test(foodId){
  console.log(foodId);
}

function generateHTML(results){
  console.log(results);
  container.classList.remove('initial');
  let generatedHTML= '';
  results.map(result => {
    generatedHTML += `
      <div class="item" data-foodid="${result.food.foodId}">
        <div class="flex-container">
          <h1 class="title">${result.food.label}</h1>
          <button id="button"  value="${result.food.foodId}" class="btn btn-primary">View</button>
        </div>
        <p  id="Food" value="${result.food.foodId}" class="item-data" >${result.food.foodId}</p>
        <p class="item-data">Brand: ${result.food.brand}</p>
        <p class="item-data">Calories: ${result.food.nutrients.ENERC_KCAL.toFixed(2)}</p>
        <p class="item-data">Fat: ${result.food.nutrients.FAT.toFixed(2)}</p>
        <p class="item-data">Protein: ${result.food.nutrients.PROCNT.toFixed(2)}</p>
      </div>
    `
  })
  
  searchResultDiv.innerHTML = generatedHTML;
  
  searchResultDiv.addEventListener("click",function(event){
    test(event.dataset.foodid);
  });  
}
```